# Rounded Corner ImageView radius doesn't match drawable radius

Tags: android, xml, imageview, android-drawable

I have a custom class that rounds the Top Left and Bottom Right corners of an image where the radius is defined in the dimens.xml as 50dp.  The corners look neat however i need various states to be applied over this, for instance when user presses the image a border is needed.

My problem is the drawable i am applying over the top of the the rounded image is showing a different radius to that of my clipped image even those they are using the same radius attribute.

[image: Red area shows radius mismatch]

Has anyone come across this issue before and if so how have you overcome this?

As an extra note the background behind this can be dynamic (image or colour) and so simply applying a colour around the border would not work in this instance.

Thanks for your time.

Rob.

Comment: yeah, those two radii dont match, you have to use the same radii

Comment: They are using the same 50dp value. It seems as though the radius is also based off of the width of the border.  I would like to be able to constrain the outside edge to the radius provided (50dp).

Comment: as you can see its not true...

Comment: You are using 2 different algorithms to perform the same task. They use different approximations. You should use the same algorithm to perform both the operations.

Answer (score 0):

The drawable radius appears to be affected by the thickness of the stroke.
The layer-list below shows the two different curves even though they have the same radius

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners
                android:topLeftRadius="75dp"
                android:topRightRadius="0dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
                />
            <size
                android:width="200dp"
                android:height="200dp" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#00FF00"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item >
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners
                android:topLeftRadius="75dp"
                android:topRightRadius="0dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
                />
            <size
                android:width="200dp"
                android:height="200dp" />
            <stroke
                android:width="8dp"
                android:color="#BC9611"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Yes this is what i have been seeing as well.

Comment: OK, but how does this post **answer** the question?! This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

Comment: I couldn't comment as it was my fist post, it didn't fix teh_raab's issue, but it shows that the arc of the curve is different based upon the thickness of the stroke.  I could see that the 1dp stroke, or a filled shape with no stroke produced the same curve as a RoundRect but a shape with a stroke produces a different result.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [ShapeableImageView](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/imageview/ShapeableImageView). It allows you both to round corners and to add a matching outline. Here's a nice [tutorial](https://itnext.io/deep-dive-into-shapeableimageview-in-android-1ba7f9a5969e).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34886085)